# Program to create a UML diagram for C++

Tags: uml, diagram

Was wondering what the easiest way to create a UML diagram for a c++ program would be? I saw some threads about a java plugin that would create the UML diagram for you, was wondering if there was one like it for C++ (using cygwin on windows).

If not any good freeware programs? I have visio I was just seeing if there were other alternatives (even used mspaint before :P)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for something similar I recommend StarUML.

Simply install it, go to the tools tab, c++, reverse engineer and follow the options.

Worked better than expected :)

Answer (score 3):

Pen and paper. Actually a pencil with an eraser might be better than a pen. No, seriously, it'll be much easier than using a program.

Answer (score 0):

If its a project then [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) can help. And [Dox](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&key=a1b43bb7c89550212cc6e8e52d78e22a&loc=http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t286080-how-to-generate-uml-for-c-code-in-windows-system.html&v=1&libid=1317990874891&out=http://www.graphviz.org/&ref=http://www.google.com.ng/search?rlz=1C1AFAB_enNG451NG452&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=create%2ba%2bUML%2bdiagram%2bfor%2bC%252B%252B&title=How%20to%20generate%20UML%20for%20C%2b%2b%20code%20in%20windows%20system?&txt=www.graphviz.org&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_13180197367651). [UML Studio](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/)

But, you can just do it manually.